# Why isn't Esc working in vim in tmux in Mintty?

Tags: ssh, terminal, vim, tmux, mintty

I sometimes use Mintty from Windows to ssh to a server, where I use vim (neovim) inside tmux. I have used this setup for years without issue. However, recently I have had the odd issue that pushing Esc doesn't seem to do anything.

It doesn't exit insert mode in vim. I've tried using ctrl+v and then pushing it, but it never registers another keypress.

Outside of tmux, vim etc. work fine in Mintty.

The only thing I've changed recently that I'm aware of that might be related is that I changed my Linux terminal, which I use when starting the tmux session, from termite to alacritty. My TERM value is `screen-256color`.

How can I get this working, or what else should I check?

Comment: Does it work when you are with Linux/alacritty?

Comment: Yes, it works without issue when I use it that way. (I primarily use Linux but occasionally boot into Windows.)

Comment: Before you start tmux, what does `echo $TERM` print in alacritty?

Comment: It's `alacritty`

Comment: I have the same issue with mintty and tmux and neovim. ESC doesn't exit vim (pun) insert mode.